# Unread messages not bold in Gmail on Chrome (Nougat)

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, gmail, chrome-for-android, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Gmail on Chrome on Lollipop (unread in bold messages are fine):

[image]

Gmail on Chrome on Nougat (unread in bold messages looks thin):

[image]

As you can see in the second image, the unread message is thinner than the first image. It's probably on bold too, just not as bold as the first image.

Anyone knows how to fix this on Nougat?

Update: This appears to be due to the default font used by Chrome on Nougat. Any ideas how to change that? Changing the Android system fonts didn't affect Chrome.

Comment: well that will work but I want to use the mobile version

Comment: Chrome Settings > Accessibility> Text scaling - see if that helps

Comment: @beeshyams I don't see "change visiblity" in the settings

Comment: You can also try typing `chrome://flags` and in the search bar reader-mode. You can try changing those settings , if it helps

Comment: @beeshyams Text scaling doesn't help and I don't see any relevant setting in `chrome://flags`. For now I am using Firefox which renders the bold fonts perfectly.

Comment: After typing `chrome://flags` and in the search bar `reader mode` I see three  flags, `reader mode triggering` , `reader mode in CCT` and `reader mode for accessibility` . I was suggesting playing with those flags, since I am not in Nougat.  . Also try updating Chrome to the latest version , if not done already

Comment: @beeshyams I tried playing with those settings, still no luck.